# Convert char to hex VALUE in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, hex

I'm a bit confused here.

I'm trying to timestamp a MIFARE card with python 2.7

What I was trying was to binascii.hexlify(char), but this seems to return a string, which made the whole timestamp TWICE as long as it was at the beginning.

I also tried hex(ord(char)), but this seems to return a string aswell....

What I really need here is the ascii values of a string, split by characters, because the writing function needs hex-values.

Have tried it like this:

```
        MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Read(4)

        tmp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m. %H:%M")
        payload = []

        #print tmp
        #print "tmp-len is %d in size" % len(tmp)

        for x in range(0,len(tmp)):
            payload.append(binascii.hexlify(tmp[x]))    
            print tmp[x]

        print payload

        MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Write(4,payload)
```

Can I just use the characters and cast them to hex, and how would I do so?
I feel a bit lost with python, since it seemed so easy with c++, yet I don't wanna give up this.

Pls help me

EDIT: The vector in the example is filled this way:

```
        # Fill the data with 0xFF
        for x in range(0,16):
            data.append(0xFF)
```

Every bit over 16 leads to an obvious overflow. The way the library is written and the MIFARE system is designed leads to a huge cringe from me.

Comment: Hex is an integer *representation*. It *must* be a string. Please clarify what your desired output is - it seems like you want an integer or bytes. Are you looking for ``time.time()`` (rounded) perhaps?

Comment: well, turned out i still get an list index out of range error, even when trying to write only a single byte to a block....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling I found out a way that would work, I assume:

It seems that you can chain together something like:

```
print type(int(hex(ord("c")),16))
```

this would return to me

```
<type 'int'>
```

I assume this will work, I'm not sure if it explicitly needs a hex value, but I can move on from here.

EDIT:
So, after making a break from work and debugging my code, it seems the problem was that the loop somehop messed up everything.
I fixed it in a way the correct timestamp would now be written to the card, the chance was this (if anybody is interested):

```
        MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Read(4)

        tmp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
        payload = []

        #print tmp
        #print "tmp-len is %d in size" % len(tmp)

        for x in range(0,16):
            try:
                payload.append(ord(tmp[x])) 
            except:
                payload.append(0xFF)
            #print tmp[x]

        print payload

        MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Write(4,payload)
```

Comment: The conversion to hex (an integer *representation*) is completely redundant! ``int(hex(ord("c")) == ord("c")``